# Custom navigation drawer in android

Tags: java, android

I have a requirement, where when the navigation drawer slides open, it should appear to be below the Main Activity with portion of the Main Activity being visible at the right and appear on top of the drawer. I am able to this achieve partially using scaling. But the navigation drawer beneath the Main Activity is not coming. Is there any way to achieve this. Below is my code.

```
 public void onDrawerSlide(@NonNull View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
                final float diffScaledOffset = slideOffset*(1 - 0.9f);
                final float offsetScale = 1 - diffScaledOffset;
                contentView.setScaleX(offsetScale);
                contentView.setScaleY(offsetScale);
                final float xOffset = drawerView.getWidth()* slideOffset;
                final float xOffsetDiff = contentView.getWidth() * diffScaledOffset / 2;
                final float xTranslation = xOffset - xOffsetDiff;
                contentView.setTranslationX(xTranslation);
            }
```

Sample image

[Sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGdyj.png)

Comment: if you dont want show the navigation drawer , then why are you using it?

Comment: It is not like that. I want to show the navigation drawer, but when the drawer opens, the extremely right edges of the drawer need to appear beneath the activity below. I just want to make the drawer slide beneath the activity, not the entire drawer but just the right side of it

Comment: Graphical representation will be more understanding. If you can add an image of the same...

Comment: @buzzingsilently i have added a sample image. The requirement is almost similar, but some portion of he right edges after the arrow icons show appear below the main activity which is being shown in white background at the right hand side

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onDrawerSlide(@NonNull View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
                int width = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.navigation_view_width);
                float moveFactor = (width * slideOffset);
                contentView.setTranslationX(moveFactor);
            }
```

try this , i think it will help

Comment: Thank you for your post, but it didn't help actually.

Comment: It is showing side by side, and not like one slightly above another

Comment: I need to elevate the activity slightly above the drawer menu when it slides and opens